# Linking bintray repo to Jcenter "Package should include sources as part of the package"

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

I have a bintray repo what I uploaded my android aar library to and I am trying to link my repo to Jcenter so that other people can import it into their project.

When I click the `Add to Jcenter` button in bintray I am taken to A `Compose message` page, I dont do anything on this page except click the `Send` button. When I click the button I get n error message in bintray saying

> Failed to send a message: Package should include sources as part of
>   the package

this is my `build.gradle` for the library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError = false
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    classpath += files(ext.androidJar)
    exclude '**/R.html', '**/R.*.html', '**/index.html'
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

publishing {
    publications {
        Production(MavenPublication) {

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/mlcamera-release.aar")
            groupId 'com.tycz'
            artifactId 'mlcamera'
            version '0.1.0'

            artifact androidJavadocsJar
            artifact androidSourcesJar

            //The publication doesn't know about our dependencies, so we have to manually add them to the pom
            pom.withXml {
                //def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                //Iterate over the compile dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                    if (it.name != 'unspecified') {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bintray {
    // Get Bintray credential from environment variable
    user = System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = System.getenv('BINTRAY_API_KEY')
    dryRun = false
    override = true
    publish = true
    pkg {
        repo = 'MLCamera'
        name = project.name
        userOrg = 'tyczj359'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        desc = 'A wrapper library for the new CameraX API and Firebase MLKit to create easier setup for MLKit usage'
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/tyczj/MLCamera.git'

        version {
            name = '0.1.0'
            released = new Date()
        }
    }
    publications = ['Production']
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-object-detection-model:19.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bintray has some preconditions to link to Jcenter.
Some are that you need a *public* maven repository, `sources` file/s, a `pom` file, etc' (more can be found at JFrog's [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Central+Repositories)). You will need to upload those files if you want to `Link to Jcenter`.

In your `build.gradle` you explicitly upload the `.aar` and also upload the `androidSourcesJar`.

From going over the `build.gradle` file it looks like **you are adding the `sources`**, you should see [error message](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/blob/5f6a3bd0fb619dc156ad2cfe9cc4add1c8ed4db2/src/main/groovy/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/tasks/BintrayUploadTask.groovy#L510) if there are any issues with collecting the files.

My suggestion is changing the order of the `from`:

```
task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
    classifier = 'javadoc'
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        Production(MavenPublication) {
            artifact androidJavadocsJar
            artifact androidSourcesJar
            groupId 'com.tycz'
            artifactId 'mlcamera'
            version '0.1.0'
            .
            .
            .
```

You can follow `gradle-bintray-plugin` [README](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin#step-7-define-artifacts-to-be-uploaded-to-bintray) with examples.

> See the section on the [workaround](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publish-doesnt-include-dependencies-in-the-project-pom-file/8544/2) for Android `pom` file dependencies.

You can also use these guides:

- [Simple way to publish your Android library to JCenter](https://medium.com/@yegor_zatsepin/simple-way-to-publish-your-android-library-to-jcenter-d1e145bacf13)
- [Publishing Gradle Android Library to Jcenter](https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/).

Comment: moving the android artifacts above my library seems to have fixed the issue!